# How to use dplyr::nest to work out the difference between two data sets

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

1) I have a transactional file called - "UBER" 
2) I also have a "Target" df to which totals I need to match my "UBER" totals  
3) I need to find the difference between Target and UBER (~ Target - UBER)  
4) and then I will overlay the difference to UBER which will then make UBER = Target

## Data for UBER - transactional file

```
UBER <- data.frame(
    Cube = c("UBER", "UBER", "UBER", "UBER"),
 Country = c("AU", "AU", "AU", "AU"),
 Product = c("0001", "0001", "0001", "0001"),
     LOB = c("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx"),
  Mth_Yr = 1:4,
 Revenue = c(5, 5, 5, 5)
    )
```

## The Target df should be

```
Target <- data.frame(
    Cube = c("Target", "Target", "Target", "Target"),
 Country = c("AU", "AU", "AU", "AU"),
 Product = c("0001", "0001", "0001", "0001"),
     LOB = c("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx"),
  Mth_Yr = 1:4,
 Revenue = c(10, 10, 10, 10)
      )
```

## I have built a function to help me with the analysis:

```
target_less_uber <- function(df){

  target <- df %>% #as.data.frame() %>%
        filter(Cube == "Target") %>%
        select(Revenue) %>% as.numeric()

  uber  <- df %>% #as.data.frame() %>%
        filter(Cube == "UBER") %>%
        select(Revenue) %>% as.numeric()      

  output <- data.frame(Overlay = target - uber)

  return(output)
```

}

## This is what I tried - which is not working

```html
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

ALL <- rbind(Target, UBER)
ALL %>%
      nest(Cube, Revenue) %>%
      transmute(Country, Product, LOB, Mth_Yr, res = map(data, target_less_uber) %>% unnest
```

Any help advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: To confirm, you wish to match the two datasets on all four variables (Country, Product, LOB, Mth_Yr)? And there's one and only one row in each dataset for each combination of the four variables?

Comment: @Z.Lin yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the `nest()` command so I couldn't troubleshoot your code there, but the following worked for me:

```
inner_join(UBER %>% select(-Cube) %>% rename(UBER = Revenue),
           Target %>% select(-Cube) %>% rename(Target = Revenue)) %>%
  mutate(overlay = Target - UBER) %>%
  select(-UBER, -Target)
```

Comment: this was an elegant and simple answer. Simplified my code very much. Thanks,  much appreciated.